# How do I convert a character to a hex value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, hex, type-conversion

Not a string, just a keyboard character in a text box.
So i don't want this code.

```
For each c as char in textbox1.text

Next
```

I want to simply know the code for converting a single character in the text box, one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single character in a textbox will still end up as a string.  Once you've checked that the string has a length of 1, you can convert it to a char by getting the first (only) char in the string:

```
char theCharacter = stringFromTextbox[0];
```

Comment: @Hexadecimal if the answer helped you really should upvote it and mark it as accepted (this is all done on the left of the answer).